# Chai testing TypeScript thrown error messages

Tags: typescript, express, chai

I'm having a hard time testing that the errors in my code are successfully throwing with the correct message. What happens is that the error is correctly throwing however my tests are failing.

The module:

```
// users.ts
const database = require('../databases/postgres');

module.exports = {
  create: async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        if (!req.body.email) {
            throw new Error('email needed');
        }

        const userCreated = await database.createUser(user);

        userCreated ? res.status(200).send('success') : res.status(409).send('user already exists');
    } catch(err) {
        next(err);
    }
  }
}
```

The tests:

```
// users.test.ts
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const users = require('./users');

describe('create()', () => {
    it('should send an error if the user does not have an email', (done) => {
        const fakeReq = {
            body: {
                password: 'abc'
            }
        };
        const fakeRes = {};

        expect(() => {
            users.create(fakeReq, fakeRes, done)
        }).to.throw(Error, 'email needed')
    });
});
```

[image]

I'm flustered by this problem and not sure if its my test, a chai/typescript incompatiability or how I'm trying use async/await? I appreciate any help.

Comment: But you have catched your error.

Comment: I am, is this not the correct way? Or should I be wrapping my tests in a try/catch block as well?

Comment: expect(() => { here must be uncached error}).to.throw.
If you are throwing error in function, you must not handle it in same function. 

In your case there must not be try/catch at all. Excluding case if db driver can throw an error.

Comment: thank you! It worked out and I learnt a bit more about error handling. If you get a chance, could you submit your second comment as an answer? I'll approve it as my accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vayrex's comment led me down the right path. I moved out the thrown errors from the try/catch block and I also went ahead and used Chai's chai-as-promised module. Below is an example of the code that worked out for me.

```
// users.ts
module.exports = {
    create:  async (req, res, next) => {
        if (!userInput.email) {
            throw new Error('email needed');
        }

        try {
            const userCreated = await database.createUser(user);

            userCreated ? res.status(200).send('success') : res.status(409).send('user already exists');
        }
        catch(err) {
            next(err);
        }
    }
};
```

The specs

```
// users.test.ts
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const users = require('./users');
const chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");

require('chai').use(chaiAsPromised);

describe('create()', () => {
    it('should send an error if the user does not have an email', (done) => {
        const fakeReq = {
            body: {
                password: 'abc'
            }
        };
        const fakeRes = {};

        return expect(users.create(fakeReq, fakeRes)).to.be.rejectedWith(Error, 'email needed');
    });
});
```